# Is there a way to do a 'scoped' add() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The main jQuery method takes a second optional argument to provide context for the search.
eg

```
$(".setA", ancestorOfSetsA);
```

However, the jQuery `add()` method does not accept this context argument. What I am trying to accomplish is:

```
$(".setA", ancestorOfSetsA).add(".setB", ancestorOfSetsB);
```

I am attempting this through a plugin that will overload the `add()` method but I can't figure out how to combine two jQuery objects into one jQuery object.

I would like to find a way to do a scoped `add()` with jQuery, but failing that, I'll write one myself if I can find a way to merge to jQuery objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a jQuery collection into `add` just as well as a selector string:

```
$(".setA", ancestorOfSetsA).add( $(".setB", ancestorOfSetsB) );
```

If you want to overload `add` then you'll need to be careful to support the all of its behaviour. Someone (a plugin you might be using) might do this:

```
$( selector ).add('<div>new element</div>').appendTo( somethere );
```

**Updated:**

Here is the current add function from jQuery modified to take a context parameter:

```
jQuery.fn.add = function( selector, context ) {
    return this.pushStack( jQuery.unique( jQuery.merge(
        this.get(),
        typeof selector == 'string' ?
            jQuery( selector, context ) :
            jQuery.makeArray( selector )
    )));
}
```

Comment: Based on your comments, here's what I came up with:

    $.fn._add = $.fn.add;
    $.fn.add = function(selector, context){
        return this._add(context?
            $(selector, context):
            selector
        );
    };

Thoughts?

Comment: I've modified my plugin to not pollute the $.fn namespace:     
var add = $.fn.add;
$.fn.add = function(selector, context){
    return add.call(this, $(selector, context));
};

I like this method as it won't need updated if jQuery.add() changes.